# chmod using 100% CPU resources

Tags: mac-pro, cpu

Since upgrading to High Sierra (now at 10.13.6) on my Mac Pro 2012, I experience regular episodes where the process chmod eats up ~100% on all 12 cores.
It happens about 15 seconds after logging in and lasts for about a minute. It then happens again later while I'm working. Of course, the computer is quite unresponsive while it lasts.
In Activity Monitor I can see 12 instances of chmod using up each core.

I haven't been able to find anything with Google regarding this issue.

Can anyone help - any ideas?

System:
Mac Pro 5,1
48 GB RAM
2 x 3,06 GHz 6-core Intel Xeon
MacOS 10.13.6

---

EDIT: Having repeated boot/login while looking in Activity Monitor each time the number of chmod processes vary from 6 to 12, and other processes are (of course) also using CPU. I may have overestimated chmod usage by about 30%, the rest of CPU resources being used by the remaining processes - sorry about that. The problem remains, though.

---

EDIT: This is the list of entries from `launchctl list` that do not begin with `com.apple`:

```
620 0   com.adobe.PDApp.AAMUpdatesNotifier.5964.3198F160-6F8E-4D56-84B0-E905086713D0  
628 0   com.company.BackgroundScheduler.9044  
-   0   com.rogueamoeba.loopbackd  
593 0   de.rme-audio.RMEfirefaceUSBAgent  
616 0   com.leapmotion.Leap-Motion.5968  
-   0   label.9ZTHPRB4MV.com.soundradix.TTLWrapperAgent  
668 0   com.avid.ApplicationManagerHelper.5960  
603 0   com.acapelagroup.InfovoxiVoxUpdater  
604 0   com.avid.applicationmanager  
-   0   com.openssh.ssh-agent  
-   0   label.9ZTHPRB4MV.com.soundradix.TTLWrapperAgent.SL  
622 0   com.rogueamoeba.ScheduleHelper.9032  
-   78  com.paragon-software.ExtFS.fsnotifyagent  
595 0   de.rme-audio.firefaceAgent  
598 0   com.code42.menubar  
623 0   com.native-instruments.NIHostIntegrationAgent.5976  
629 0   com.abyssoft.teleport.5972  
-   0   com.adobe.AAM.Scheduler-1.0  
-   0   com.oracle.java.Java-Updater  
-   0   com.iconfactory.iPulse.5996  
-   0   com.paragon.updater  
601 0   com.spotify.webhelper  
615 0   jp.plentycom.boa.SteerMouse.9028  
583 0   com.prosofteng.DGMonitor  
-   0   com.Arturia.ArturiaSoftwareCenterAgent  
-   0   com.google.keystone.user.agent  
-   0   com.leapmotion.Leap-Motion
```

Comment: chmod ? and nothing else showing.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of activity monitor?

Comment: chmod

Change access permissions, change mode

Comment: it should do it only once, not repeatedly, unless you or some app changes the permissions all the time

Comment: @Buscar: Other processes are running, too, and per my edit above they use the remaining approx. 30%. And yes, it does repeat, but when and how many times vary from day to day.

Comment: OK, lets try to find out who is changing the permissions to make the CHMOD run so often, it does not run at all on my Mac. In terminal type `launchctl list` then find anyone that DOES NOT begins with  `com.apple.`

Comment: I've added the list in my post. I am new to posting here, I have a bit of trouble with the formatting, sorry.

Comment: Do you use anything like Launch Control or Lingon to manage your launch entries? If so, you can try to toggle each of the entries off one-by-one to see which is the culprit.  Both of those programs have trials that I think will let you at least toggle.

Comment: @Buscar웃: The problem is solved. Your idea to check what was starting 'chmod' let me to use 'lsof' to investigate. 'chmod' was working on an Avid cache in 'Library/Caches'. I deleted this cache and since then, chmod hasn't been running. So thanks for your input.

Comment: @JesseP.: Thanks for your input; as you can see in my comment above, I found the culprit and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution: Using `lsof` in Terminal located in the utility folder, I could see that `chmod` was accessing an Avid cache in `~/Library/Caches` which I simply deleted. Now `chmod` doesn't run anymore.

Comment: you are welcome and well done. Maybe you can elaborate how did you find it, so others can profit form it.

Comment: @Buscar웃: Do you think it needs more elaboration? I'm not sure what more to add.

Comment: We usually like bit more explanation for those who do not know how to do what you did. Maybe the list of your `lsof` ! and `Library/Caches` is not correct path.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for correcting the path. Unfortunately, the output of `lsof` no longer exists, so I can't add it now. But I'll remember to do so in the future.